# Reporting services only displaying the last row

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have built a report pretty basic just a table wiht 45 rows of data.  Problem is its only showing one row of data and its the last row.  It displays just fine in the dataset and proc.  any suggestiosn?

The table is in the body of the report.

Comment: Can we see the code/query you're running?  It sounds like whatever loop you're using to display the data is flawed, unless I'm misunderstanding how this all works.

Comment: could you provide a snapshot of your report in design view please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably you have put the fields in the header of the report 
build your first report with the **report creation wizard** and after change it the way you want it

Answer (score 2):

make sure the fields don't have first() or last() in them.

Answer (score 1):

or you can just try create a table in the detail part (not header nor footer) of your report and drag some fields from the datasource explorer into the table, after click the preview tab and you will some a table with some records. good luck

Answer (score 0):

You could check if there are any filters associated with the dataset. Click on the Edit DataSet button and check the Filters tab.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is insert a new table; this time, don't delete the header (I found out I deleted it before), and then create the table again.

(Restarting can always help fix something in IT... hilarious...ha ha)